# Transposing rows into column with specific order in python

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, output, transpose

I have a csv file contains an output from model in the following format
`X1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3 q1 q2 q3`

And I want to transpose this into three columns using Python

```
X1 y1 q1
X2 y2 q2
X3 y3 q3
```

Can anyone help please ?

Comment: Some example of the actual input data would be nice, maybe the first two or three lines from the CSV file? Also, what is the output format? Another CSV file?

Comment: As a CSV file I assume you actually mean `X1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3,q1,q2,q3` ?  Does it contain multiple rows?